# C++, other variable getting affected by scanf statement

Tags: c++, scanf

The value of t becomes 0 after the scanf statement
cant understand why, t is affected by this statement, even if t=100 the program runs for only 1 iteration!
PS first question here! and it took 100 minutes to write this! always pops up some problem! :@

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#define MOD 1000000009
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{

     int n,m;
     scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
     vector< pair<long long int,char> > a(m);
     long long int x;
     int i;
     char d[1];
     for(i=0;i<m;i++)
     {

          scanf("%s%lld",d,&x);// t becomes zero after this
          a[i]=make_pair(x,d[0]);
     }
     sort(a.begin(),a.end());
     long long int ans=1;

     for(i=0;i<m-1;i++)
     {

        if(a[i].second!=a[i+1].second)
        {
           ans=ans*(a[i+1].first-a[i].first);
           ans=ans%MOD;

        }
     }

     ans=ans%MOD;
     printf("%lld\n",ans);

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: +1 for your patience!

Comment: You have a buffer overflow. Since this is C++, you should use the stream operators instead of scanf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are causing a buffer overflow when calling `scanf("%s%lld",d,&x)`.  `d` only has room for 1 `char`, but `%s` reads until a white space character is encountered.  Even if the user types in only 1 character before whitespace, it will still overflow because `%s` writes a null terminator at the end of the buffer it writes to. That is why `t` gets modified.

If you really want to read only 1 `char`, you need to either:

1. declare `d` as just a `char` and use `%c`:

   ```
   char d;
   scanf("%c%lld",&d,&x);
   ```
2. declare `d` as `char d[2]` so it has room for a null terminator and use `%1s`:

   ```
   char d[2];
   scanf("%1s%lld",d,&x);
   ```

BTW, you have to be careful with things like `scanf("%d%d",&n,&m)`.  Think of what happens if the user types in `"123456"` and you wanted to read it as `123` and `456` separately.  The user would have to type `"123 456"` instead.  So just be aware of that.

Comment: thanx a lot!! nicely explained!!